# How do I solve the error "The type 'MasterPage2' already contains a definition for 'head' "

Tags: c#, asp.net

Each time I build my MasterPage.master.aspx, I get an error that reads:

> The type 'MasterPage2' already contains a definition for 'head'

This error appears for all the protected values in my MasterPage.master.cs file. How do I fix the error please?

Below is the header for my master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage2" %>
```

And here is my **MasterPage.master.cs** codes:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class MasterPage2 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    protected ContentPlaceHolder head;
    protected HtmlAnchor A1;
    protected HtmlAnchor A2;
    protected HtmlAnchor A9;
    protected SiteMapDataSource SiteMapDataSource1;
    protected Menu MainMenu;
    protected HtmlAnchor home;
    protected HtmlAnchor A3;
    protected HtmlAnchor A4;
    protected HtmlAnchor A5;
    protected HtmlAnchor A6;
    protected HtmlAnchor A7;
    protected HtmlAnchor A8;
    protected HtmlGenericControl submenu;
    protected ScriptManager ScriptManager1;
    protected LoginName LoginName1;
    protected Literal litbal;
    protected Literal litdate;
    protected UpdatePanel up12;
    protected ContentPlaceHolder content1;
    protected ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder2;
    protected ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder3;
    protected ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder4;
    protected Label lblCreatedBy;
    protected ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder1;
    protected HtmlForm form1;
    protected DefaultProfile Profile
    {
        get
        {
            return (DefaultProfile)this.Context.Profile;
        }
    }

    protected HttpApplication ApplicationInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Context.ApplicationInstance;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.litdate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("D");
        if (((object)this.Page.User.Identity.Name).ToString() != "")
            this.litbal.Text = DB.ExecuteScaler(string.Format("Select Agent_current_bal from AgentBasicInfo where Agent_ID='{0}'", (object)((object)this.Page.User.Identity.Name).ToString().ToLower())).ToString();
        else
            this.up12.Visible = false;
        this.submenu.Visible = ((object)this.Page.User.Identity.Name).ToString() == "admin";
        this.lblCreatedBy.Text = "Created By: otieno t oloo";
    }
}
```

Below here is my **MasterPage.master.aspx** codes:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">   
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />   
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
        <!--header starts -->
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <img  src="~/Images/logo.gif" alt="logo" runat="server" /></div>
            <div id="logoright">
                <div id="topbar1" style="float: right">
                    <div class="empty" style="padding-top:3px; padding-right: 10px; background: #f1f1f1; height: 25px">
                      <a id="A1" href="~/Agent_list.aspx" runat="server">Agents</a>|&nbsp; <a href="~/AboutUs.aspx" runat="server">About Us</a>|&nbsp; <a id="A2" href="~/Faq.aspx" runat="server" >FAQ</a>|&nbsp; <a id="A9" href="~/Feedback.aspx" runat="server">Feedback</a>|&nbsp;
                        <a href="~/contactus.aspx" runat="server">Contact Us</a></div>
                    <div class="empty" style="background: #f1f1f1">

                        <img height="25" alt="" src="~/Images/top_curve2.gif" width="32"  runat="server" /></div>
                    <div class="empty" style="width: auto; height: 25px; text-align: center">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="empty" style="float: right; margin: 9px 0px 8px; ">
                    <img height="56" alt="" src="~/Images/paper.gif" width="286"  runat="server" /><asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" 
                            ShowStartingNode="False" />
                            </div>
                <div id="navigation"> 
                <div>
                <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
                DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False">
                <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="menu" />
                <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuItem" />
                <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="menuSelectedItem" />
                <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="menuPopup" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuPopupItem" Font-Strikeout="False" />
                <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="menuPopupItem" />
                <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="menuItemHover" />
            </asp:Menu>
                </div>
            <div id="submenu" runat="server">
            <ul id="submenulist">
            <li><a id="home" href="~/AdminArea/HomeForAdmin.aspx" runat="server">Basic Info</a></li>
             <li><a id="A3" href="~/AdminArea/CreateAgent.aspx" runat="server">Create Agent</a></li>
              <li><a id="A4" href="~/AdminArea/All_Agents_info.aspx" runat="server">Agent List</a></li>
               <li><a id="A5" href="~/AdminArea/Deposit.aspx" runat="server">Deposite</a></li>
               <li><a id="A6" href="~/AdminArea/Agent_search.aspx" runat="server">Search Agent</a></li>
              <li><a id="A7" href="~/AdminArea/Bus_list.aspx" runat="server">Bus List</a></li>
               <li><a id="A8" href="~/AdminArea/feedback_list.aspx" runat="server">FeedBack List</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up12" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="border-header" style="height: 25px;" valign="middle"
                                                align="left" width="600">
                                                Welcome <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />, Rs.<asp:Literal ID="litbal" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="border-header-date" style="height: 25px" valign="middle" align="left"
                                                width="200">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litdate" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="content1" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footerlinks">
                    <div style="float: left">
                       Copyright © 2010, All rights reserved &nbsp; <span class="orange11">l</span> &nbsp; <a href="~/Privacypolicy.aspx"  runat="server">Privacy policy</a>&nbsp; <span class="orange11">
                            l</span> &nbsp; <a href="~/TermsandConditions.aspx"  runat="server">Terms and conditions</a>&nbsp;
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: right; text-align: right">
                       <asp:Label ID="lblCreatedBy" runat="server"></asp:Label>  
                    </div>                    
                </div>                
            <!--footer ends -->
            <div>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably in the file MasterPage.master.designer.cs already exists a control named head.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a few reasons:

1. You have another class somewhere in your project that is also called `MasterPage2`
2. You need to clean and rebuild your project
3. You have a control named head in you `master.cs` and a control with the same name in your `master.designer.cs`

Comment: MasterPage2 is a class inside MasterPage.master.cs file. Are you suggesting I change the class name? Kindly advise!

Comment: This error persists even on changing the class name to something else. It just adopts that name and display the error. Could it be something within my MasterPage.master.aspx file?

Comment: Thank you but am kind of lost. From those codes I've posted, is it possible to point out the area? For the head error, could this be the cause? `code`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`code`

Comment: have you tried removing the `protected ContentPlaceHolder head;` from master.cs file?

Comment: Yes I've tried and when I do, I get more n more errors

Answer (score 1):

Are you *nesting* `MasterPages`?.

**IF** so the error is pointing to the cause. You have 2 `head` elements in the resulting page (combined). Aside from the server-side error, you'll likely have a malformed HTML document that gets rendered (2 sets of `<html/>` declarations and `<head/>`, `<body/>`, etc. elements).

Refer to this [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x2b3ktt7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on how to nest `MasterPages`. In a nutshell, the nested `MasterPage` is like a "templated" `UserControl`.

Hth...